# Create new rows in Pandas Dataframe from cells like "A BCD 1-5"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that contains product inventory information. Currently some of the products are listed as groups of five, such as "A BCD 1-5", "A BCD 6-10", etc. I need to turn these groupings into 5 rows, so that each row would be in the format "A BCD 1", "A BCD 2", "A BCD 3", etc. I'm thinking that I'll need to use a bunch of different regular expressions to find the "1-5", "6-10" and create new rows from that, but am a bit stuck getting started.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'a', 'var2': '1-5'},
           {'var1': 'b', 'var2': '6-10'}])
```

From this:

```
|Name|Inventory Number|
|:---|---:|
|x|A BCD 1-5|
|x|A BCD 6-10|
```

To This:

```
|Name|Inventory Number|
|:---|---:|
|x|A BCD 1|
|x|A BCD 2|
|x|A BCD 3|
|x|A BCD 4|
|x|A BCD 5|
|x|A BCD 6|
|x|A BCD 7|
|x|A BCD 8|
|x|A BCD 9|
|x|A BCD 10|
```

Comment: How big is your csv?

Comment: About 15000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
>>>  df['Inventory Number'].str.extract(r'(.*) (\d+)-(\d+)') \
                           .dropna(how='all') \
                           .apply(lambda x: [f'{x[0]} {i}'
                                      for i in np.arange(int(x[1]), int(x[2])+1)],
                                  axis='columns').explode()

0     A BCD 1
0     A BCD 2
0     A BCD 3
0     A BCD 4
0     A BCD 5
1     A BCD 6
1     A BCD 7
1     A BCD 8
1     A BCD 9
1    A BCD 10
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
df[['Inventory Name', 'var2']] = df.pop(
    'Inventory Number').str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.assign(var2=df.var2.str.split(
    '-').apply(lambda x: np.arange(int(x[0]), int(x[1])+1))).explode('var2')
df = df.astype(str).set_index('Name').agg(
    ' '.join, 1).reset_index(name='Inventory Number')
```